# Can I make columns in a Google document?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

I am using Google Docs and have a document file. I would like to add columns within this, and was wondering if that is possible. I can't find how to do it internally.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No.  The closest thing you can do is use a table.

Comment: For what it is worth- you can make the table and then make the table color white. That way it looks like columbs

Comment: See my [answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/98713/88163)

Answer (score 2):

Today, Google [announced](https://drive.googleblog.com/2016/09/what-you-love-about-google-search-now.html) several enhancements to Google Drive and Google Docs, including the columns handling feature:

> You can now easily split your document into multiple columns in Docs.
>   Just choose “Columns” in the “Format” drop-down menu when you need
>   more formatting options to get your point across.